# How to approach web app development?

Tags: python

I have been going through Flask and it seems that now I have a decent understanding to go ahead and build a web application. However I want to know how would I approach the problem. For eg: 
I decide to build a blogging application. The first thing I do is write down all the things that come to my mind, from user registrations to posting data on the blog to publishing it on the site

But after that I just get into coding. I know that is not the right approach. I have heard of UML diagrams, workflow diagrams and stuff. It would be great if someone could just outline the steps they would follow for building a large application and then I could go ahead and learn more about them.For eg,it could be something like the below:-

1. Collect requirements
2. Draw UML diagrams
3. Draw workflow diagrams
4. start coding

Please suggest an exhaustive list so that I can make my approach much more systematic.
Thanks

Comment: I guess this question is best asked at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ where subjective discussion on programming is encouraged. Here the questions pertaining to code issues and objective questions are answered. you might get a lot of participation for this question there.

Answer (score 0):

That all sounds like a lot of work.  Try [web2py](http://www.web2py.com/).  You get a lot of stuff, such as user registrations and updating data for a blog, for free.  Then just write the code.  web2py is not as freeform as flask, there is a "one right way to do things".  But for beginners, that can be helpful until you have enough experience to go it on your own.

Comment: Thanks cjrh! but I guess web2py is not for me.I had read the docs once and tried out building an application too but during the entire process I felt as if I was learning a totally new language. But yes it is definitely a good framework.However it would be best on my part not to spark off a debate on this.